# Spreadsheet : every possible combination of 2 columns into one single colum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

and sorry if this question looks familiar, I saw a lot of similar problems but couldn't understand the trick, and I completely stuck.

I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns :

**A** with Countries
**B** with their code

```
  A             B
Belgium        BE
England        EN
France         FR
Luxembourg     LX
Netherlands    NL
Spain          SP
```

I'm trying to generate generate a matrix representing all the possible travels : Travel from A to A, from A to B, from B to A, and from B to B. **The only restriction is not to travel from a country to itself**.

At the end I want to generate the result in a single column **C**, like this :

> Travel from Belgium to England
>  Travel from Belgium to France
>   Travel from Belgium to Luxembourg
>  Travel from Belgium to
>   Netherlands
>  Travel from Belgium to Italy
>  Travel from Belgium
>   to Spain
>  Travel from England to Belgium
>  Travel from England to
>   France
>  Travel from England to Luxembourg
>  Travel from England
>   to Netherlands
>  Travel from England to Italy
>  Travel from
>   England to Spain
>  etc
>  Travel from Belgium to EN
>  Travel from
>   Belgium to FR
>  Travel from Belgium to LX
>  Travel from Belgium to
>   NL
>  etc
>  Travel from BE to EN
>  Travel from BE to FR
>   Travel from BE to LX
>  etc
>  Travel from BE to England
>  Travel
>   from BE to France
>  etc

Can anyone help me with that ? I tried several tricks with concatenation and JOIN, but I don't get anywhere ...

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Use a two dimension array in VBA and loop through. Get started on that and if you run into trouble, come back and edit your question to include your effort and we can help sortt you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can run through each value in column A and associate it with a staggered value from column B but you will have to perform some mathematical trickery using the [INT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-4D0598D4-FAC0-4ED3-BFBC-BE6DC8544183) and [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-0CAF2C6C-891D-4A0B-B618-3B0D60296809) to have the sixth entry in column A associated with the first entry in column B.

[image: INT and MOD to stagger lookup]

The formulas in C2:E2 are,

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$7, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(A$2:A$7)-1))+1)
=INDEX(B$2:B$7, MOD(MOD((ROW(1:1)-1), (COUNTA(B$2:B$7)-1))+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(B$2:B$7)-1))+1, COUNTA(A$2:A$7))+1)
="Travel from "&C2&" to "&D2
```

There may be a more elegant way of looping through the destinations while skipping the origin but this works and it is not calculation intensive despite the apparent complexity of the formula(s).

I've used the [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) to determine the number of entries rather than hard-code in ordinal numbers. You should be able to transcribe this for more or less entries by following and modifying the referenced cell ranges.

Comment: Very nice, though this is a problem where VBA is more natural (but OP didn't ask for it).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll work on it from there.